# Have the answer. Need the problem.

Tags: combinatorics

I took a combinatorics course last semester and to my surprise it was really interesting. A common theme in the class was to to come up with questions given the answer. I am working on a problem at the moment that escapes my powers of creativity. It goes as follows:

Come up with a problem whose answer is:

$$(k+1) \binom{k+n+3}{k+2}-\binom{k+n+2}{k}$$

Does anyone know a good way to solve problems of this nature? Or can help me come up with a scheme to tackle this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Why was it a surprise?

Comment: My impression of the course was in bad shape. My friends who had taken the course were not very fond of it. They got tired of counting, and doing so in ridiculous ways: their words. I found it very enjoyable, and at times marvelous.

Comment: An obvious candidate problem would be: *"Write down the expression $(k+1) \binom{k+n+3}{k+2}-\binom{k+n+2}{k}$."*

Comment: Update: I found one solution to this problem.

Comment: @jvargas, care to share?

Comment: @vonbrand: Sure, the number of ways of walking a quarter plane, say Quadrant I, from the origin to a lattice point (a,b) such that a+b+2 steps must be taken to get there.